# Hypergeometric Distribution Function?

Tags: functions, probability-distributions

I'm looking for a function that I can use in excel to calculate the probabilities of having certain cards in an opening hand.

For example a function that will calculate the probability to get AT LEAST 1 of 'x' card in an initial hand of 7 cards from a 60 card deck where the number of successes of 'x' equals 'a'.

I'd also like a function that can do the same thing but calculate getting AT LEAST 1 'x' card AND AT LEAST 1 'y' card where number of successes for 'x' and 'y' are 'a' and 'b' respectively.

Sorry I'm no Math wizz so ask if I didn't make sense on something.

Comment: By "number of successes of 'x' equals 'a'" do you mean there are 'a' 'x' cards in the deck?

Comment: Yes. Total number of 'x' cards in the deck is equal to 'a' and 'y' = 'b'

Answer (score 0):

Hint: it's a lot easier to calculate this from the complement of NOT getting any of 'x'.

So, in the first case, on the first draw you have a probability of $1-\frac{a}{60}$ of not drawing 'x', a probability of $1-\frac{a}{59}$ on the second draw, and so on.

Another hint is that $\overline{A\cap B}=\overline{A}\cup \overline{B}$.